# find average of a column avoiding null data

Tags: php, mysql, average

i Have this table :'grade' with columns as below:
'student_id'     'score'

to call 'student_id' i use

```
<?php echo $myData['student_id'];?>
```

to call 'score' i use

```
<?php echo $myData['score'];?>
```

when i want to call the average of column 'score' i use

```
$query="Select AVG(score) as average FROM grade";    
$result_array=mysql_query($query); 
$average= mysql_fetch_array($result_array);
```

problem is, there is a `null` data in column `score` and average is counting it as `0`.

so here is the example data taken from column score:
problem:

```
'10', '10', '10', '' , '10' will give average of 8.
```

what i want is like this:

```
'10', '10', '10', '' , '10' will give average of 10
```

any help how to fix this?

Comment: Have you just tried adding `where` criteria?  `where score is not null`?  Or if it's indeed blank, `where score != ''`...

Comment: Thank you...it works with    where score != ''

Answer (score 0):

you can have a simple if statement that counts the '' (nulls) and then subtract that from the data size

```
for (i =0; i < resultarray.length; i++){
   if (resultarray[i] == ''){
    nullcounter++;
   } else { 
    sum += sum; 
  } 
} 
average = sum /(resultarray.length - nullcounter);
```

Comment: in pseudo code 
'for (i =0; i < resultarray.length; i++){
  if (resultarray[i] == ''){
    nullcounter++ 
  } else {
    sum += sum;
  }
}

average = sum /(resultarray.length - nullcounter);'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's giving such a result because aggregate functions like SUM, COUNT, AVG etc. discards NULL values by default.

Anyways, you could try this to be safe:

```
SELECT AVG(score) as average 
FROM grade
WHERE score IS NOT NULL
```